# wordpress infinite scroll with url change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I using ajax load more plugin in wordpress , its is working infinite scroll of posts  , now i want when new post loads the url must shown as new url

this is my page code :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php 
    $infinite = ot_get_option('infinite_load', 'on');
?>
<div id="infinite-article" data-infinite="<?php echo esc_attr($infinite); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr($infinite); ?>">
    <?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        <?php
            $id = get_the_ID();
            $format = get_post_format();
            if ($format == 'video' ){
                $post_style = get_post_meta($id, 'video-post-detail-style', true) ? get_post_meta($id, 'video-post-detail-style', true) : 'style1';
                get_template_part( 'inc/post-detail-styles/'.$format.'-'.$post_style );
            } else if ($format == 'gallery' ){
                $post_style = get_post_meta($id, 'gallery-post-detail-style', true) ? get_post_meta($id, 'gallery-post-detail-style', true) : 'style1';
                get_template_part( 'inc/post-detail-styles/'.$format.'-'.$post_style );
            } else {
                $post_style = get_post_meta($id, 'standard-post-detail-style', true) ? get_post_meta($id, 'standard-post-detail-style', true) : 'style1';
                get_template_part( 'inc/post-detail-styles/'.$post_style );
        }
        ?>
    <?php endwhile; else : 
    endif; 
//$next_post = get_next_post();
//if (!empty( $next_post )){ 
    ?>
    <!--
<div class="infinite-navigation">
  <div  class="infinite-previous"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?></a></div>
 </div>
-->
<?php// } ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

here my code working for infinite scroll but when new post loads the url not changing any best suggestions to implement this case.

the demo is something i have seen like this required [demo](https://qz.com/1041929/to-bust-the-myth-that-muslims-dont-belong-in-india-just-look-at-the-armed-forces/)

Console Log :

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'click' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at globalEval (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:2538), <anonymous>:2:52)
    at j (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:29568)
    at k (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:29882) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:2:52)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: The url update part is handled using JavaScript using pushState api, please check the JavaScript code or errors using developer tools in browser.

Comment: console log added

Comment: share me the site url?